# package sun.net.www.protocol.https is not visible

Tags: java, migration, java-11

I am migrating java application from java-8 to java-11 facing an issue
package sun.net.www.protocol.https is not visible.
My code is like
URL url = new URL(null, strServletUrl, new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());

so how to get https handler in java-11 as it not visible in class being in base package.

Answer (score 6):

The best translation of

```
 URL url = new URL(null, strServletUrl, 
                   new sun.net.www.protocol.https.Handler());
```

is:

```
 URL url = new URL(strServletUrl);
```

Unless something weird is going on, there is no point explicitly instantiating the standard stream protocol handler for a builtin protocol.  Just let the JVM find a handler in the standard way.  Then your code won't need to depend explicitly on this (internal) class.

---

If something weird >is< going on, then you may be able to work around this problem *for now* using `--add-exports`.  However, this is liable to stop working in a newer version of Java as access to the internal APIs is progressively closed off.

So my advice would be to figure out some other way to do ... whatever requires this.